# Asp.Net Core 1.0.0: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL Migration error

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

My `Startup.cs`:

```
    services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o =>
        o.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]
    ));
```

My `project.json`:

```
"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
```

My project's `dotnet --version`:

> 1.0.0-preview2-003121

Then `dotnet ef migrations add First`says

> The current CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator cannot scaffold
>   operations of type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.NpgsqlCreatePostgresExtensionOperation'.
>   Configure your services to use one that can.

How can I specify an appropriate generator? Or maybe I'm doing wrong somewhere? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Npgsql EFCore provider, and has already been fixed: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/58. The next release will contain the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the version, you may need to add `"Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design": "1.0.1"` to your `project.json` file to get this to work. See [this issue comment](https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL/issues/58#issuecomment-235411517)